# SpatialFilterClass to WFS filter for ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, wfs

I want to translate a MapServer Query URL to a WFS GetFeature query.
Then I try to serialize a SpatialFilterClass to WFS filter.
any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Find here a BitBucket project which contains the code (Java) to make a WFS connection using ArcObjects:

https://bitbucket.org/bugramovic/fme_arcobjects_interop_example

Comment: Thanks but after some investigation, I prefere to translate the URL with GDAL/OGR.